# Cursor on object after stage

Tags: cursor, createjs, tween

I have a animation in which first cursor is pointer on whole stage and after then our animation timeline stops and cursor of stage becomes default and cursor over an object present on stage is made pointer and click event is added to it. but cursor is not working properly when cursor of stage is used. Is there any other way of doing this.